# How can I re-start tint2 after laptop un-sleep and after internet connection is detected?

Tags: internet, tint2

I am running

- arch linux 6.4.2-arch1-1 and
- openbox wm v3.6.1 with
- tint2 bar version 17.0.2 and
- systemd v253.5-2-arch

Everything is up to date.

On my tint2 bar I display time dependent information such as the weather etc.

I don't want the tint2 bar to update every few seconds because this will use too much system resources, and I may get banned from the weather site etc for too frequently polling for new data.

So I have tint2 set to update every hour, which seems reasonable.

However when I unsleep my laptop, to turn it back on, tint2 starts before I get an internet connection, so it refreshes before it is able to collect the information updates eg weather.

Can anyone suggest how after un-sleeping I might get tint2 to do a re-start immediately **after** detecting an internet connection.

So want to

- on any of the following:  un-sleep, re-boot, switch on, un-hibernate
- after connection to internet has been detected re-start tint2 (so it will have eg fresh weather reports rather than useless old ones)

I am thinking this might involve a simple script that utilises `systemd`.

Here is what I have so far:

I have created a systemd service file called `restart_tint2.service` and placed in `/etc/systemd/system/` with this in it ..

```
[Unit]
Description=This service runs once only after the arch linux laptop is 1 turned on after suspend 2 re-booted 3 turned on after being switched off 4 turned on after being hibernated

After=suspend.target


[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/home/$USER/Dropbox/linux_config/script_tint2_restart_after_sleep/restart_tint2.sh


[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Which points to this script ...

```
#!/bin/bash

# function to check internet connectivity
check_internet() {
  ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null 2>&1
}

# function to restart tint2
restart_tint2() {
  if pgrep -x "tint2" >/dev/null; then
    pkill -x "tint2"
  fi

  sleep 1

  tint2 & disown
}

# check internet connectivity
check_internet

# if internet is not available, wait and check again
while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
  sleep 5
  check_internet
done

# restart tint2 after internet connection is detected
restart_tint2


exit 0
```

After I suspend the laptop and re-awaken it with the power button, it kills tint2 but does not re-start it.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Open to any means of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a systemd service text file called `restart_tint2.service` and place it in `/etc/systemd/system/` with this content

```
[Unit]
Description=This service runs once only after the arch linux laptop is 1 turned on after suspend 2 re-booted 3 turned on after being switched off 4 turned on after being hibernated

After=suspend.target hibernate.target


[Service]
Type=oneshot  
# point to the location of the script given below
ExecStart=/home/$USER/Dropbox/linux_config/script_tint2_restart_after_sleep/restart_tint2.sh


[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

The below script, call this `restart_tint2.sh`, is called by the above service file when the conditions are met

```
#!/bin/bash



# function to check internet connectivity

check_internet() {
  ping -c 1 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null 2>&1
}



# function to restart tint2

restart_tint2() {

# the below is the only solution that works, 
#  both killing, then re-starting tint2

killall -SIGUSR1 tint2


}

# check for internet connectivity

check_internet

# if internet is not available, wait and check again
while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
  sleep 5
  check_internet
done

# restart tint2 after internet connection is detected
restart_tint2


exit 0
```

That's it, working solution